Using a static token with firebase authentication and by passing authentication with firebase in C# ASP.NET Core
I have a web application that users do not need to sign up to see data, but also a mobile app that requires authentication and I am using firebase which returns an authorization token for the api calls.
I want to use a static firebase token for all requests from my website, but currently when trying to bypass authentication of the token, I am getting expired errors. I tried to set it to ignore the life time, but now I am getting an error:

The signature key was not found"

How can I force my C# ASP.NET Core Web API to ignore authentication/authorization validation of a certain static token?
This is my current code in startup.cs:
// ConfigureServices method
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
          {
              options.Authority = $"https://securetoken.google.com/{firebaseProjectId}";
              options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
              {
                  ValidateIssuer = true,
                  ValidIssuer = $"https://securetoken.google.com/{firebaseProjectId}",
                  ValidateAudience = true,
                  ValidAudience = firebaseProjectId,
                  ValidateLifetime = false
              };
          });

// Configure methods

// Add custom middleware 
app.UseMiddleware<FirebaseTokenMiddleware>(anonymousToken);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

FirebaseTokenMiddleware:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System;
    
namespace BrickAPI.Middlewares
{
    public class FirebaseTokenMiddleware
    {
            private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
            private readonly PathString _documentation = "/api-docs";
            private readonly PathString _testAPI = "/test";
            private readonly string _staticToken;
    
            public FirebaseTokenMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, string staticToken)
            {
                _next = next;
                _staticToken = staticToken;
            }
    
            public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
            {
                // Check if the request path starts with /swagger or /redoc
                if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_documentation) || context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_testAPI)) 
                {
                    // Skip execution of the middleware for Swagger/Redoc paths
                    await _next(context);
                    return;
                }
    
                var tokenValidator = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<FirebaseTokenValidator>();
                var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
    
                // Check if the token is missing
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    // Return a response indicating that the token is missing
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; // Unauthorized
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Authorization token is missing in the request.");
                    return;
                }
               
                // Check if the token matches the static token
                if (token.Replace("Bearer ", "") == _staticToken)
                {
                    // Set user information in the request context or perform any desired action
                    context.Items["UserId"] = ""; // Replace with the actual user ID
    
                    // Proceed to the next middleware in the pipeline
                    await _next(context);
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    // Validate Firebase token for non-static tokens
                    var userId = tokenValidator.ValidateTokenAsync(token);
    
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
                    {
                        context.Request.Headers["UserId"] = userId;
                        await _next(context);
                        return;
                    }
    
                    // Token validation failed, return unauthorized
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; // Unauthorized
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Authorization token is invalid.");
                }
    
                //await _next(context);
            }
    }

    public class FirebaseTokenValidator
    {
            public string ValidateTokenAsync(string tokenWithPrefix)
            {
                // Remove the "Bearer " prefix from the token string
                var token = tokenWithPrefix.Replace("Bearer ", "");
    
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    // Log a warning indicating that the token is missing
                    Console.WriteLine("Firebase token is missing in the request.");
    
                    // Return null to indicate that the token could not be validated
                    return "Invalid Token";
                }
    
                try
                {
                    // Validate the Firebase token
                    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
    
                    // Get the expiration claim
                    var exp = jsonToken?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "exp")?.Value;
    
                    if (exp != null && long.TryParse(exp, out var expUnix))
                    {
                        // Convert the Unix timestamp to DateTime
                        var expirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(expUnix).UtcDateTime;
    
                        // Check if the token has expired
                        if (expirationDateTime <= DateTime.UtcNow)
                            //Token lifetime has expires
                            throw new Exception("Token has expired");
                    }
    
                    // Extract user ID from the token
                    var userId = jsonToken?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "user_id")?.Value;
    
                    return userId;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Log an error indicating that token validation failed
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to validate Firebase token: {ex.Message}");
    
                    // Return null to indicate that the token could not be validated
                    return null;
                }
            }
    }
}

Any suggestions on how to bypass authorization for that token, and just mark it as valid without firebase validating it? Thanks
